# Character elemental function. Give a parameter as char-length to interface?

Tags: function, interface, fortran

The question is why i get an error saying the `integer` **`charlen`** is a `real` when i pass it as the length definition of a character elemental function. To be more specific, the folowing **MWE** *works*:

```
program chararr
implicit none
!!
integer,parameter :: charlen = 20
!!
interface
character(len=20) elemental function adjR(a)
character(len=*),intent(in) :: a
end function
end interface 
!!
character(charlen) :: test(3), testR(3)

test = ["hej", "hoj", "haj"]
testR = adjR(test)

print*, test
print*, testR

end program 

character(20) elemental function adjR(a)
character(len=*),intent(in) :: a
adjR = adjustr(a)
end function
```

but the line `integer,parameter :: charlen = 20` does nothing. When i change the function and interface definitions like this

```
character(len=charlen) elemental function adjR(a)
```

i get the following error:

```
charmin.f90:7:14:

 character(len=charlen) elemental function adjR(a)
              1
Error: Expression at (1) must be of INTEGER type, found REAL
```

**UPDATE**

The solution of Alexander is in code:

charmin.f90:

```
program chararr
use char_mod, only: charlen, adjR
implicit none
!!
!interface
!character(30) elemental function adjR(a)
!character(len=*),intent(in) :: a
!end function
!end interface 
!!!
character(charlen) :: test(3), testR(3)

test = ["hej", "hoj", "haj"]
testR = adjR(test)


print*, test
print*, testR
print*, charlen !!! it is here
end program
```

char_mod.f90:

```
module char_mod

implicit none
integer,parameter :: charlen = 30

private
public charlen, adjR

contains

character(charlen) elemental function adjR(a)
implicit none
character(len=*),intent(in) :: a
adjR = adjustr(a)
end function

end module
```

To compile:

```
gfortran -c char_mod.f90 
gfortran charmin.f90 char_mod.f90 -o program
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`charlen` is defined in the scope of the program, but the function `adjR` is outside that scope. Consequently, `charlen` is not accessible, and since the function does not have `implicit none` defined, it is interpreted as a real variable.

One solution to this would be to put `adjR` in a module, and make `charlen` a module variable.

Comment: Thank you! I got a range of errors until i realized that that I have to remove the interface block! It works, and i think this is the first time I really needed a module to actually solve a problem.